# аналог Angular FormControl.setValue во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, form, angular, input

Недавно начал учить Vue.js. До этого работал Angular-ом. Как я понял, наиболее всеми предпочтительный способ работы с формами/инпутами - двусторонняя привязка через `v-model`. Тем не менее, хотелось бы знать, есть ли во Vue аналог `setValue(yourVal, { emitEvent: true })`.

Предположим, у меня есть инпут с односторонней привязкой: `<input v-bind:value="inputVal" @change="changeInput">`.

В данном случае, метод changeInput сработает только перестать фокусить инпут (или при самом вводе текста, если сменить `@change` на `@input`). Существует ли аналог, ангуляровского `setValue`, чтобы программно вызвать хэндлер change ивента?

Comment: @yar85, согласен полностью насчёт того, что подходы везде разные, просто ангуляр предоставляет в этом случае, такую возможность. Хотелось узнать, можно ли в конкретном случае сохранить односторонний биндинг, и, при этом, не нагромождая доп логику, покрыть все кейсы

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102938/discussion-on-question-by-j-mark--angular-formcontrol-setvalue--vue-js).

Comment: То есть тебе нужно, чтобы, когда input.value меняется реактивной привязкой v-bind, у input-a срабатывало событие oninput/onchange?